# CSS - Transition does not work properly in JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have used a JavaScript for loop to change the `className` property of a group of DIV's that have same class.
I'm trying to change of appearance of each div by the changing the `className` property so that the CSS transition activates and effects the each DIV.
The problem is that the transition **ONLY** affects the first DIV.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="accor hide" id="chosen">
      od
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>To</li>
      <li>Pr</li>
      <li>La</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="accor hide">
      En
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>fa</li>
      <li>Co</li>
      <li>Co</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="accor hide">
      Sp
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.accor + ul {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease
}
.hide + ul {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function init() {
  var chosen = document.getElementById("chosen");
  chosen.onclick = toggleDivs;
}

function toggleDivs() {
  hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("accor hide");
  for(var i = 0; i <= hideDivs.length; i++) {
    hideDivs[i].className = 'accor';
  }
}
```

When I click the DIV with the `id` of "chosen" I want to make all the DIV's with the class "accor" slide down like like jQuery's `$.fn.slideDown(...);`.

If I change the JavaScript a little bit the transition will effect the first two DIV's.

Here is my changed JavaScript:

```
hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('accor hide');
hideDivs[0].className = 'accor';
hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('accor hide');
hideDivs[0].className = 'accor';
```

I think this is because when I used the for loop (above) `i` was initially set to `0` and `i` did not increment so the transition only effected the first DIV.

Comment: Try to separate HTML, CSS and JavaScript where possible it makes your code easer to understand and read. E.G: you don't need `<body onload="init();">` instead you can modify your JavaScript and use `window.addEventListener("load", init, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pugazh have other fix so i want to post hear for diversity.

```
function toggleDivs() {
  var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('accor')
  for (var i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++)
  menu[i].classList.toggle('hide');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `hideDivs[i].className = 'accor';` with `hideDivs[0].className = 'accor';`
I did this because each time you execute `toggleDivs();` the class `hide` is removed from the element, you want to toggle the DIV's not always hide them.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
  var chosen = document.getElementById("chosen");
  chosen.onclick = toggleDivs;
}

function toggleDivs() {
  hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("accor hide");
  for(var i = 0; i <= hideDivs.length; i++) {
    hideDivs[0].className = 'accor';
  }
}
```

```css
.accor + ul {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease
}

.hide + ul {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="accor hide" id="chosen">
      od
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>To</li>
      <li>Pr</li>
      <li>La</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="accor hide">
      En
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>fa</li>
      <li>Co</li>
      <li>Co</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="accor hide">
      Sp
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry, but i have edited the code that init() will run at <body onload = 'init()'>, so didn't run it in javascript file.

Comment: yeahhh, it work. thanks you very much, but it still strange for me. can u explain more. why the hide div remove?

Comment: @VuHa It's simple say, you have five elements with class `hide` once you change one of their class to anything else then there will be only 4 elements remaining so the index gets back to zero

Comment: Yes. it mean for loop always devaluate the hideDivs after a loop. Thanks all of you very much.